# Flex: What is the best way to place an image in specific coords on canvas

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I know that the question may seem very easy. I am trying to display an image on canvas.
I need to do it in AS, and also I need to locate image in specific coordinates.

Could you please suggest how to do it

Comment: `img.x = 20; img.y = 30;` - am I missing something?

Comment: srsly, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an image at a  specific location within a canvas:

```
            var myImage:Image = new Image();
        myImage.source =  "image1.png";
        myImage.x = 100;
        myImage.y = 100;
        myCanvas.addChild(myImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the dataToLocal() method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/chartClasses/ChartElement.html#dataToLocal%28%29).